# Do positive and negative samples after flipping have an effect on the result?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I'm using the Machine Learning algorithm xgboost. When I'm flipping positive label(before was 1) to 0, negative label (before was 0) to 1 like this, my AUROC changes a little.

from 0.778~ to 0.779~ , I  don't know why.

1. I used scale_pos_weight;
2. same other params;
3. set.seed is also the same.

Comment: try to put your code in the question, to make it understandable

Comment: If I correctly understand the question, you're changing the train-set, and this leads to some difference in the test results. This makes sense - what exactly is the question?